# Items without regions in Oracle APEX?

Tags: button, region, oracle-apex

I'm currently building a web form using APEX that is losely modelled after a "wizard" style.  That is, I have forward and back buttons for most pages, etc, etc.

The problem I have is that it seems all my buttons need to be part of a region and that region needs to located in a pre-determined section of the page.

I would prefer to be able to place my buttons where I want them rather than include them into a specific region.  I just want them at the bottom of the page.

At the very least, I need to get a region to ignore all my theming so that it can be "invisible" so that only the buttons are showing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this example](http://htmldb.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=22644) I just created on apex.oracle.com.  The buttons are in a separate region that has no template associated with it.

In fact, it would be better to create a new region template for the buttons region, with no decoration applied.  This would give you more control over the location and spacing of the buttons.  At its simplest this template could be defined as:

```
<div id="#REGION_STATIC_ID#" class="myButtonTemplate">
  #BODY#
</div>
```

(The ID is optional, but I like all my tags to have IDs so I can reference them in Javascript and CSS if required.)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up creating my own region as per your code block example.